# Найти неверные ссылки на изображения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть текст в котором встречаются следущие ссылки на изображения

```
<img src="/dir/namepic.jpg">
<img src="/dir/namepic.gif">
<img src="/dir/namepic.jpeg">
<img src="/dir/namepic/">
<img src="/dir/namepic2>
```

Ссылки на строках 4,5 битые, тк не содержат расширений jpg/gif/jpeg и/или закрывающих кавычек.

Как с помощью регулярного выражения выбрать только строки, не содержащие нужных расширений и удалить их?

Comment: первые три тоже битые - нет закрывающих кавычек

Comment: Точно! Исправил

Comment: а они именно такие, или  в строке могут быть другие тэги а в img другие атрибуты?

Comment: можно и без регулярок просто проверять, что строка не содержит ".jpg", ".gif" и т.д.

Comment: @Эникейщик если проверять, что не содержит ни одно из списка, это все равно, регулярка, только попроще

Answer (score 0):

не дождался ответов от автора поста, но вот таким выражением можно пробовать искать

```
^.*?<img[^>]+src="[^"]*(?<!\.(jpg|gif))(?<!\.jpeg)">.*$
```

**[демо и описание](https://regex101.com/r/Sgvl9J/1)**